# Website Backup and Download

Tags: backup

How to download the whole website in general and *.blogspot.com in particular? Note that I don't necessary have admin access to that website. In fact I am just trying to download a third party website just in case it goes into flames...

Comment: I hope you're not trying to download every page of every subdomain of blogspot.com...

Comment: see also http://superuser.com/questions/14403/how-can-i-download-an-entire-website

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found httrack (http://www.httrack.com/) very useful for this in the past.

If you use any tool to try download an entire site (not just httrack), make sure you show a little consideration to the site. See [httrack's "what not to do" page](http://www.httrack.com/html/abuse.html) for some pointers on that.

Comment: +1 because httrack creates a local mirror that you can browse.

Answer (score 6):

you can use wget to mirror the website [ provided it does not have flash or javascript based navigation ].

look [here](http://fosswire.com/post/2008/04/create-a-mirror-of-a-website-with-wget/) or just check command's [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html). wget is available for unix systems and [windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm).

Comment: the first link doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2):

wget I believe will crawl a page for you

the option -r I believe is what you want. Note in the following snip the part about converting links for offline viewing. Since you said you want to have this page just in case it "goes up in flames" this will allow you to browse it locally.

from the man page

```
Wget can follow links in HTML and XHTML pages and create local versions of remote web
sites, fully recreating the directory structure of the original site.  This is sometimes 
referred to as "recursive downloading."  While doing that, Wget respects the Robot 
Exclusion Standard (/robots.txt).  Wget can be instructed to convert the links in 
downloaded HTML files to the local files for offline viewing.
```

Comment: While backing up a blog with wget, I found it useful to add the "--span-host" option for the links/images that are not hosted in the same domain.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have admin access to the site to use the backup tool for the site then you could backup the HTML contents of your pages, from viewing the source the source, or if you just want the actual written content of articles, copy that. You can also download your images and other attachments from the site. [This article](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2007/02/how-to-backup-blogger-blog.html) gives you details of how you could do that in a more efficient way.

You can also use wget if you have it to get hold of the site information.

Bear in mind though that this will not give you the info you need to just take your blog and run it somewhere else, there is a whole PHP backend behind blogspot that is loading your sites etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something a little more advanced that wget, take a look at Black Widow

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone. [SiteSucker](https://ricks-apps.com/osx/sitesucker/) is a super Mac OSX app that does what you want. `wget` doesn't always do what you'd expect especially with JS based menus, etc, even with its plethora of options. And `httrack` is not a visual tool on Mac, it's installed with homebrew. SiteSucker is by far the simplest and the most reliable tool for *local download of all html and assets*, as if you're running a full static version of that site.